# svnlook through php gives one line

Tags: php, svnlook

I have a simple php exec command that calls svnlook. If I run the command through the terminal I get all the output I expect. If I run it as shown below, I only get the last item.

```
$list = exec("svnlook changed -r ".$urlCleaned." ".$SVNEXPORT); 
echo $list;
```

Can I buffer the output? If so how? And will that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's by design and is explained:

> `string exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] )`
>
> **Return Values**
>
> The last line from the result of the command. If you need to execute a command and have all the data from the command passed directly back without any interference, use the `passthru()` function.
>
> To get the output of the executed command, be sure to set and use the *output* parameter.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

```
exec("svnlook changed -r ".$urlCleaned." ".$SVNEXPORT, $output);
var_dump($output);
```

Alternatively, [`shell_exec`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) returns everything.